# Use a project react that has already been generated

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I got a react project through bitbucker and I would like to use it. But every time I use npm install to install project dependencies it gives the following error:

```
hile resolving: eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.2.1
npm WARN Found: eslint-plugin-import@2.21.2
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-import
npm WARN   dev eslint-plugin-import@"2.21.2" from the root project
npm WARN   2 more (eslint-config-airbnb, eslint-import-resolver-typescript)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer eslint-plugin-import@"^2.22.1" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.2.1
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
npm WARN   eslint-config-airbnb-base@"^14.2.0" from eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint-plugin-import@2.26.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-plugin-import
npm WARN   peer eslint-plugin-import@"^2.22.1" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@14.2.1
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
npm WARN     eslint-config-airbnb-base@"^14.2.0" from eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.0
npm WARN     node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb
```

And if I try to start the project with yarn start or yarn run the following error appears:

```
ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'start'
```

I have node versions 16 and 14, I set version 14 as default. I've tried running through 16 as default and it still won't. When I click inside vscode to find out which node version is available, it gives me version 10. Could someone help me? And when I hover, for example, my mouse over the route: react, it says that this module doesn't exist, either.